# Store a list of certain numbers globally and use it as the value of parameter in a PL/SQL function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have certain numbers eg., (1,2,3,7,8) which need to be stored in an object (let's say, l_list) and this l_list will used as the value of the parameter in a function while calling a select query.

Storing data globally:

```
l_list := (1,2,3,7,8);
```

Creating a function:

```
create or replace function f_get_result (p_list number)
return varchar2
as 
  l_result varchar2(100);
Begin
  select l_code
  into l_result
  from table_1;

  return l_result;

end f_get_result;
```

Calling the function in select query:

```
select f_get_result(l_list) from dual;
```

Till now I have tried to define the datatype of the parameter as type table and varray. But, it didn't work.
Here is the code which I used:

```
-- creating a type ---
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE num_array AS TABLE OF varchar2(100);
```

```
-- the function ---
create or replace function fn_id_exp(p_branch in num_array) 
return varchar2 
   is 
     txt varchar2(1000); 
     txt_1 varchar2(1000); 
begin 
   for i in 1..p_branch.count loop 
      select branch_name into txt_1 from tbl_branch 
      where branch_code = p_branch(i); 
     
      txt := txt ||txt_1||chr(10); 
end loop; 
return txt; 
end;
```

```
-- the select query ---

select fn_id_exp(num_array('100','200')) from dual;
```

expectation: select fn_id_exp(l_list) from dual; , need to use this much, num_array should not be there,

where l_list is an object which is storing certain numbers like (100,200,300).

Please, help me in this, I am bit new in this. Can somebody, give me an an appropriate example regards this?

Note: It doesn't matter where and what datatype these number are getting stored. Requirement is just to call all the numbers(1,2,3,7,8) in this:

```
select fn_id_exp(l_list) from dual;
```

Comment: Please describe what you want to achieve. This may be solved with pure SQL (which is a standard way to access relational data) using `in` condition, PL/SQL doesn't make sense here

Comment: `p_list` would need to be a collection, not a scalar number. You've said you tried to define it as a table and varray, but you haven't shown that code, and "it didn't work" doesn't tell us anything helpful. Your function doesn't even use the parameter, so it is unclear why you need it. Where are you defining your 'global' `l_list` - in a package, or is this part of an anonymous block, or passed in from an application, or...?

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE num_array  AS TABLE OF varchar2(100);

create or replace function fn_id_exp(p_branch in num_array)
return varchar2 is
      txt varchar2(1000);
      txt_1 varchar2(1000);
    begin
        for i in 1..p_branch.count loop
            select branch_name 
            into txt_1
            from tbl_branch
            where branch_code = p_branch(i);
            
            txt := txt ||txt_1||chr(10);
        end loop;
        
        return txt;
    end;
    
select  fn_id_exp(num_array('100','200')) from dual;

Comment: Above mentioned is working fine till now. In select query instead of ('100','200') , this 100, 200 should be stored in some object example l_list which could be used as like as following: select  fn_id_exp(num_array(l_list)) from dual;

Comment: It would be better if we can use as "select fn_id_exp(l_list)) from dual;"

Comment: Please add that information to your question as an edit, not a comment, and format it. If that is working, then what are you really asking - how to create and store a 'global' list? You'll need to explain where you want it and how it will initially be populated. Is it something you want to populate from a client/application, so each session creates its own list? Or a real global list, maybe as a constant in a package declaration - though then why not store them in a table?

Comment: Hi Alex, I have edited the question and added the code and exact requirement. Please, see and provide your feedback.  And also let me know if any other info is required. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option, which doesn't require you to use your own type, is to use Oracle's built-in types.

Here's an example; function returns employees that work in departments passed as a collection.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test (par_deptno in sys.odcinumberlist)
  2    return sys.odcivarchar2list
  3  is
  4    retval sys.odcivarchar2list;
  5  begin
  6    select ename
  7      bulk collect into retval
  8      from emp
  9      where deptno in (select * from table(par_deptno));
 10
 11    return retval;
 12  end;
 13  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select * from table(f_test(sys.odcinumberlist(10, 20)));

COLUMN_VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MILLER
KING
CLARK
FORD
ADAMS
SCOTT
JONES
SMITH

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Note that such a result might be more convenient than returning a string which "mimics" rows in a table (whose values are separated by *line feed* character), as you'd still might need to split them into rows if you wanted to further process the result.

---

You said:

> expectation: `select fn_id_exp(l_list) from dual;` , need to use this much, `num_array` should not be there

But - why not? What's wrong with `num_array` (or whichever type name you'd use)? That's the syntax, you should follow it if you want to get the result. Silly requirements, in my opinion.

Anyway: you could pass a string of e.g. comma-separated numeric values such as in this example; you'll have to split them to rows. See if it helps.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test (par_deptno in varchar2)
  2    return sys.odcivarchar2list
  3  is
  4    retval sys.odcivarchar2list;
  5  begin
  6    select ename
  7      bulk collect into retval
  8      from emp
  9      where deptno in (select regexp_substr(par_deptno, '[^,]+', 1, level)
 10                       from dual
 11                       connect by level <= regexp_count(par_deptno, ',') + 1
 12                      );
 13
 14    return retval;
 15  end;
 16  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select * from table(f_test('10, 20'));

COLUMN_VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SMITH
JONES
CLARK
SCOTT
KING
ADAMS
FORD
MILLER

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks @Littlefoot for your reply, now I am able to fetch the data by using "select f_test ('100,200,300') from dual;" Now, just need to store the  "'100,200,300'" in an object so that it can be used as "select f_test (l_list) from dual;"

Answer (score 0):

Use a collection:

```sql
CREATE TYPE number_array AS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

Then:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION fn_id_exp(
  p_branch in number_array
) return varchar2
IS
  txt varchar2(1000);
BEGIN
  SELECT LISTAGG(branch_name, CHR(10)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY rn)
  INTO txt
  FROM   (SELECT ROWNUM AS rn,
                 COLUMN_VALUE AS id
          FROM   TABLE(p_branch)) i
         INNER JOIN tbl_branch b
         ON (i.id = b.branch_code);

  RETURN txt;
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
select fn_id_exp(number_array(100,200)) from dual;
```

Given the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl_branch (branch_code, branch_name) AS
SELECT 100, 'Leafy Stem' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 200, 'Big Twig' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| FN_ID_EXP(NUMBER_ARRAY(100,200)) |
| --- |
| Leafy Stem Big Twig |

---

#### However

It may be simpler to not use a function and just use a query:

```sql
SELECT branch_name
FROM   tbl_branch
WHERE  branch_code IN (100, 200)
ORDER BY branch_code;
```

or, if you want to use the array::

```sql
SELECT branch_name
FROM   tbl_branch
WHERE  branch_code MEMBER OF number_array(100, 200)
ORDER BY branch_code;
```

or, pass in an array as a bind parameter (via JDBC, etc.) then:

```sql
SELECT branch_name
FROM   tbl_branch
WHERE  branch_code MEMBER OF :your_array
ORDER BY branch_code;
```

Which output:

| BRANCH_NAME |
| --- |
| Leafy Stem |
| Big Twig |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-OQtACQG)

---

#### Update

If you want a static array then you can create a package:

```sql
CREATE PACKAGE static_data IS
  FUNCTION getList RETURN NUMBER_ARRAY;
END;
/
```

With the body:

```sql
CREATE PACKAGE BODY static_data IS
  list NUMBER_ARRAY;

  FUNCTION getList RETURN NUMBER_ARRAY
  IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN list;
  END;
BEGIN
  list := NUMBER_ARRAY(100, 200);
END;
/
```

then you can use it in your query:

```sql
select fn_id_exp(static_data.getlist()) from dual;
```

or

```sql
SELECT branch_name
FROM   tbl_branch
WHERE  branch_code MEMBER OF static_data.getlist()
ORDER BY branch_code;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QcevJOV5)